# After conversion to VB Public Shared Event Idle(sender As Object, e As System.EventArgs)' is an event, and cannot be called directly

Tags: c#, vb.net, winforms, eventhandler, raiseevent

I have converted my Face Recognition App to VB and it is giving an error which I am unable to resolve...

```
 Public Sub initialise_capture()
    grabber = New Capture()
    grabber.QueryFrame()
    'Initialize the FrameGraber event
    If parrellelToolStripMenuItem.Checked Then
        Application.Idle += New EventHandler(AddressOf FrameGrabber_Parrellel)
    Else
        Application.Idle += New EventHandler(AddressOf FrameGrabber_Standard)
    End If
End Sub
```

In C# it working fine but in VB its not working. Please help me resolve this problem as I am novice to .NET

Comment: wheres the error? please provide substantial question so we could help you.

Comment: AddHandler Application.Idle, AddressOf FrameGrabber_Standard

Comment: I got the solution...:) this is the solution i was using event handler of c# but in VB we have a different Event handler